Why does Stryker JS hang when used with angular ng test?
This is my project structure:

stryker.config.json:
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@stryker-mutator/core/schema/stryker-schema.json",
  "_comment": "This config was generated using 'stryker init'. Please see the guide for more information: https://stryker-mutator.io/docs/stryker-js/guides/angular",
  "mutate": [
    "apps/1-web/src/**/*.ts",
    "!apps/1-web/src/**/*.spec.ts",
    "!apps/1-web/src/environments/*.ts",
    "!apps/1-web/src/**/*.html",
    "!apps/1-web/*.yml",
    "!apps/1-web/src/**/*.generated.ts",
    "!apps/1-web/src/test.ts",
    "!apps/1-web/src/**/*.graphql",
    "!apps/1-web/src/**/*.scss"
  ],
  "tsconfigFile": "tsconfig.json",
  "testRunner": "karma",
  "ignorers": ["angular"],
  "karma": {
    "configFile": "apps/1-web/karma.conf.js",
    "projectType": "angular-cli",
    "ngConfig": {
      "testArguments": {
        "project": "1-web"
      }
    },
    "config": {
      "browsers": [
        "ChromeHeadless"
      ]
    }
  },
  "reporters": [
    "progress",
    "clear-text",
    "html"
  ],
  "logLevel": "trace",
  "concurrency": 4,
  "concurrency_comment": "Recommended to use about half of your available cores when running stryker with angular",
  "coverageAnalysis": "perTest",
  "dryRunTimeoutMinutes": 30,
  "karmaConfigFile": "karma.conf.json"
}

Package.json:
"@stryker-mutator/core": "^8.6.0",
"@stryker-mutator/karma-runner": "^8.6.0"
"@angular/cdk": "15.2.9",
"@angular/common": "15.2.10",
"@angular/compiler": "15.2.10",
"@angular/core": "15.2.10"
"karma": "6.4.1",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
"karma-coverage": "^2.0.3",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^3.0.3",
"karma-jasmine": "5.1.0",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "2.0.0",
"karma-junit-reporter": "^2.0.1",
"karma-parallel": "^0.3.1"

When the stryker command "npx stryker run" is run, source files are instrumented, sandbox folder is created and working directory is changed to the sandbox directory. I see the below output in the terminal and nothing else happens after that. Navigating manually to the karma runner on http://localhost:9876/# shows "localhost refused to connect."
16:17:47 (28448) DEBUG AngularProjectStarter Starting Angular tests: ng test --progress=false --karma-config=C:\dev\monorepo\web.repo\node_modules\@stryker-mutator\karma-runner\stryker-karma.conf.cjs  --project=1-web
16:17:47 (28448) DEBUG AngularProjectStarter Starting Angular tests: ng test --progress=false --karma-config=C:\dev\monorepo\web.repo\node_modules\@stryker-mutator\karma-runner\stryker-karma.conf.cjs  --project=1-web

When I "cd" into the sandbox folder and run the below command manually:
ng test --progress=true --karma-config=apps/1-web/karma.conf.js --project=1-web
I see this on http://localhost:9876/# 
The browser just hangs there. No console errors on the debug window either. The debug window is just blank and console shows "Skipped 0 tests"
I tried removing ngConfig->testArguments-> project and running Stryker, same result.
But if I run "ng test" in the sandbox folder, all tests are running.
